# Twitter signin returns nothing on ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-twitter-signin

I have simple code where i use `react-native-twitter-signin` to log in to twitter. I followed the instructions to set up my project. When i click in the button that calls this method:

```
const { RNTwitterSignIn } = NativeModules;
const twitterAuth = async () => {
console.log('point 1')
await RNTwitterSignIn.init(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
console.log('point 2');
}
```

on android i get to signin and works accordingly. but on ios i’m stuck on that await and don't get to point 2. Nothing happens even in the debug console. I tried everything i could find on here. Please help.